# Tree View and double select

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Hi. I have a `TreeView` were it expands when I double click on it. And I have method which shows only one node (which is selected, other open nodes close automatically)

```
void treeView1_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in e.Node.Parent.Nodes)
        {
            if (node != e.Node)
                treeView1.CollapseAll();

        }
    }
```

Problem is that this method works when I single-click the mouse, but the tree collapses when I double-click it. I need that `treeView1_BeforeSelect` will execute on double-click.

Thnx

Comment: Please explain the need for double clicking here, if we understand the desired behaviour we can recommend a better solution.

Comment: Double click jus for more user frendly

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because `BeforeSelect` is executing before the default behavior that double-clicking induces.  Therefore, your desired result is wiped out.  Handle the double click event yourself, and do the same thing:

```
public void treeView1_NodeMouseDoubleClick(Object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in e.Node.Parent.Nodes)
    {
        if (node != e.Node)
            treeView1.CollapseAll();
    }

    e.Node.Expand();
}
```

Comment: But now all my tree closed to the root and I didint see Root->child , before I saw it.

Comment: Programmatically expand the node that was clicked after collapsing all

Comment: How can I do that? It is impossible to do that in that class?